Active bandpass filter - unwanted oscillations ( noise)
I designed a bandpass filter with a cut-off frequency of 0.1hz and 110khz
when I applied a 1khz -20khz sine wave to the input of my band pass filter, I saw oscillations (ringing) at the zero cross points.
(It is obvious that there is a higher frequency harmonic here)
When I do an fft analysis, I see oscillations between 4-5 MHz. Around -40dbV, at a level of approximately 8-10mV.I think one of the filters is producing an oscillation. (I tried with different power supplies. The noise is not coming from the power supply.)What is the solution to this or what is the point I missed? capacitance value selection?
When I did AC sweep in Spice simulations there was no problem, everything was perfect.





High pass filter (opa192)


order Active High Pass Filter
Topology: Sallen-Key
Stage Gain:1
Cutoff Frequency:0.1Hz


lowpass pass filter THP210

Multiple-Feedback Topology 2. order Active Low Pass Filter (Gain:1) fully differential Output
Cutoff Frequency:110KHz

Did you see it after stage 1? How did you measure it on stage 2? Please link data sheets for the chips.

Hey Andy, Unfortunately I don't have the prototype pcb  with me, I measured the first highpass filter, the oscillation is not coming directly from here, but there are distortions here too.

You should sort out the signal coming from stage 1 and then move on to see what comes out of stage 2.
